# Listbox as a WrapPanel: How to make the item I click on "pop" as a new window?

Tags: wpf, animation

I have ListBox, with a WrapPanel as its ItemsPanelTemplate. I've modified the ItemTemplate so that my items are displayed as Tiles.

So far, so good.

The problem I have now, is that I'd like, when I click on an item of the ListBox, to have an animation which would make the item grow up, and go to the center of the screen, so it acts like a modal window, where I could edit the content of the item I clicked on.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: FluidMoveBehavior from the [Blend SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10801) might help.

Comment: Thanks. Indeed it might help to move the content of the tile to a grid which would be on top of the listbox. But as the latter grid would be invisible, until some content is added to it, is there any way to know when the animation of the behavior has stopped, so I can make the overlay grid visible?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [my own custom popup control](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/08/20/popup-panel-for-wpf/) for this kind of thing. It has a built-in animation which will expand the Popup to full size when grown, and the Popup is part of the visual tree so you can place it whenever needed in the Visual Tree

```
<Grid x:Name="PopupParent">

    <ListBox x:Name="TileListBox">
        ...
    </ListBox>

    <!-- Popup -->
    <local:PopupPanel local:PopupParent="{Binding ElementName=PopupParent}"
                      local:PopupPanel.IsPopupVisible="{Binding IsPopupVisible}"
                      Content="{Binding PopupContent}">

        <local:PopupPanel.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyTileViewModel}">
                <local:MyTileView />
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:PopupPanel.Resources>

    </local:PopupPanel>

</Grid>
```

Comment: So I would have one popup per tile I display, and the popup would grow up from the position of the tile in the listbox? And eventually grow down when closed, to the previous position?

Comment: @Mike You would have one Popup for your ListBox, and when you need to display an item you would set the item as the `PopupContent` and set `IsPopupVisible` to true. I edited the code sample to add the ListBox to where it should be.